# Dell T5400 AMD RX460 GPU needs old Nvidia GPU

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-precision, amd-graphics-card

I am not one to ever post anything so I apologize if this is the wrong place!

My Google skills have failed to find an answer for something very strange that I've  encountered. After days of looking online, I haven't found anyone ask this question. A quick background on my issue...  I realize that the answer might be that the AMD RX460 isn't compatible buuuuuuut.

While trying to find out why the AMD RX460 installs just fine but the driver crashes no matter what... I saw somewhere (maybe here?) that it might work if I install the old GPU as well, it's a Nvidia Quadro. Just one post by someone,  somewhere, wasn't obvious either. I tried just about everything you could think of to make it work and someone made a note that it could work but was ignored.

And what do you know? It does... If I don't get an answer then hopefully some one will see this and save themselves countless hours with a workaround.

Does anyone have any idea why that is? Would it be possible to maybe emulate the Nvidia GPU? Or does any one have anything in mind that I could try to get around this?

This old GPU is a pain because it heats up causing other issues. (Mainly my PC turns into a extremely loud jet after a few minutes of game play, the new GPU is in a tight spot due to its size, uneccesary heat being added to the machine kills me and just the thought of it taking up space is annoying.)

Some observations I made:

Removing the old GPU will cause the new GPU to stop working So basically the AMD GPU NEEDS the Nvidia GPU to be physically installed.

The Nvidia GPU needs to be the primary graphics card or the AMD GPU will stop working.

I tried to disable SERR in the Bios, it did nothing.

I have Windows 10 installed (oh to any one having audio issues, change it to "ON" instead of "AUTO"  in the BIOS, it'll work...)

BIOS is up to date.

I tried just about everything you could imagine to get the AMD card to work on its own before I found out that installing the old Nvidia will make it work. (Reinstall, clean install, reformat, install old/new drivers, under the red moon while on a table with a horse mask :P , new motherboard!! *fried it by accident lol*)

Sorry for the long post! The answer might be "not compatible, it shouldn't even work what the heck. "  but I thought I would try.

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is you are trying to ask here?

Comment: Any ideas why the AMD GPU only works if the Nvidia card is installed? I'm hoping that I'll be able to find a way to remove the old GPU once I figure that part out.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Not 100% yet but it fits, found it while Googling "T5400 AMD BIOS GPU" and going to the second link.  This page was the first somehow?? Lol. Basically the T5400 needs a video card that supports Legacy BIOS. The RX460 cards are apparently only UEFI compatible. It'll work as long as you have a Legacy BIOS compatible card as your primary.

Comment: Might want to post that as an answer, and reference your sources along with that.

Comment: K! Went ahead and posted as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Not 100% yet but it fits, found it while Googling "T5400 AMD BIOS GPU".  Link of where I found this is below. Basically the T5400 needs a video card that supports Legacy BIOS. The RX460 cards are apparently only UEFI compatible. It'll work as long as you have a Legacy BIOS compatible card as your primary.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1568840.0;prev_next=next